# Joining objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically, I have this array of objects:

```json
[
    {
        "user": "joe",
        "loginsLogout": 28
    },
    {
        "user": "noJoe",
        "loginsLogout": 2
    },
    {
        "user": "joe",
        "loginsLogout": 4
    },
    {
        "user": "joe",
        "totalTime": 2123617,
        "sessions": 52
    },
    {
        "user": "joe",
        "requests": 1
    },
    {
        "user": "noJoe",
        "requests": 1
    }
]
```

And I need to transform the structure of it into this:

```json
[
    {
       "user":"joe",
       "loginsLogout":32,
       "totalTime":2123617,
       "sessions":52,
       "requests":1
    },
    {
       "user":"noJoe",
       "loginsLogout":2,
       "requests":1
    }
]
```

Can you help me figure out how to accomplish this?

Comment: So what code is building the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution I found using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

- Iterate through each item in the array.
- Keep track of whether we have seen the `user` before.
- If we have merge the arrays increasing the values.
- If not add the array to the result array.

**Full code:**

```js
let data = [
    { user: "joe", loginsLogout: 28 },
    { user: "noJoe", loginsLogout: 2 },
    { user: "joe", loginsLogout: 4 },
    { user: "joe", totalTime: 2123617, sessions: 52 },
    { user: "joe",requests: 1 },
    { user: "noJoe", requests: 1 },
];


function merge(obj1, obj2) { 
    Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key) => {
        if (obj2[key] && typeof obj2[key] === "number") obj2[key] += obj1[key];
        else obj2[key] = obj1[key];
    });
    return obj2;
}

let result = [], seenBefore = [];

data.forEach((object) => {
    let foundHere = seenBefore.indexOf(object.user);

    if (foundHere !== -1) {
        result[foundHere] = merge(result[foundHere], object);
    } else {
        result.push(object);
        seenBefore.push(object.user);
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hello friend, thank you very much for your reply. Worked perfectly.

Unfortunately my english is worse than my js.

Thank you very much.